# Moving over multiple related tables

Tags: sql-server

I have about 10 tables that all relate to each other. They are populated from a single flat file and refreshed daily. Some of the tables contain raw data and some contain analysis computed off of the raw tables.  Since the data in the tables are populated from a single source and they relate to each other we need a way to transfer them simultaneously or as close as possible. Currently we build the tables in a staging schema and then transfer them over, one at a time to the live schema. My concern is what happens if something occurs between the table transfers and half of the tables are live and the other half are stuck in staging. Then the data won't match up. We want either all or none transferred. I am wondering if anyone has experienced something similar to this and if yes how was it handled?

Comment: Just so I'm clear, you're doing a full flush and fill every day? Also, what mechanism are you using to move from staging to dbo? SSIS? Stored procedures? A combination of those? Partition switching? Something else I haven't thought of? How you're doing it will dictate how you build out your risk mitigation, error-handling, and recovery models.

Comment: yes a full flush and fill. Combination, we are calling a stored procedure that transfers the tables. So far we are switching from staging schema to the live, but we did consider partition switching, would partition switching be helpful here?

Answer (score 0):

First, the answer to your initial question; how to make the data transfer all-or-nothing.

That's actually pretty straight forward, since you're using a stored procedure to do the data transfers. You can wrap the entire data transfer process in an explicit transaction. That way, if anything goes south in the middle of the process, EVERYTHING gets rolled back.

So, with a little pseudo code:

```
BEGIN TRY

  BEGIN TRANSACTION

    INSERT Table1 ...
    SELECT ...
      FROM ...

    INSERT Table2 ...
    SELECT ...
      FROM ...

    ...

    INSERT TableN ...
    SELECT ...
      FROM ...

    COMMIT TRANSACTION

END TRY
BEGIN CATCH

  ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
  --Other fancy error handling --

END CATCH;
```

The downside to this, and it might be a deal breaker, is that this will hold a table lock on all of the tables until the whole transfer is done.

Which raises the second point. Partition switching.

For a flush and fill like this, it can be a great solution. `ALTER TABLE...SWTCH` typically executes in milliseconds. You can still wrap the `SWITCH` statements in an explicit transaction, but since everything is so much faster, the locks won't last nearly as long.

```
BEGIN TRY

  BEGIN TRANSACTION

    ALTER TABLE staging.Table1 SWITCH PARTITION 1 TO live.Table1 ...

    ALTER TABLE staging.Table2 SWITCH PARTITION 1 TO live.Table2 ...

    ...

    ALTER TABLE staging.TableN SWITCH PARTITION 1 TO live.TableN ...

    COMMIT TRANSACTION

END TRY
BEGIN CATCH

  ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
  --Other fancy error handling --

END CATCH;
```

Kendra Little wrote up a terrific blog post that gets into much, much more detail about how to make this an non-invasive as possible in your environment.

[Why You Should Switch in Staging Tables Instead of Renaming Them](https://littlekendra.com/2017/01/19/why-you-should-switch-in-staging-tables-instead-of-renaming/)